# Error with my syntax in creating a simple table using SQL with Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a simple table with a primary key, however I am getting an error message stating, "Syntax Error in CREATE statement".

```
CREATE TABLE BUILDING 
(Building_ID INTEGER(15) NOT NULL, 
Building_Name TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
Building_Type TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
Department_ID INTEGER(15))
CONSTRAINT BUILDING_pk PRIMARY KEY (Building_ID)
);
```

Comment: You have an extra parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parantheses before the CONSTRAINT operator and put a comma after the line before it.

```
CREATE TABLE BUILDING 
    (Building_ID INTEGER(15) NOT NULL, 
    Building_Name TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
    Building_Type TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
    Department_ID INTEGER(15),
    CONSTRAINT BUILDING_pk PRIMARY KEY (Building_ID)
);
```

After that, you should be good to go.